# How to modify laravel view file names

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

after using artisan make:auth, laravel creates views in storage/framework/views using scrambled file names. I suspect the filenames are created using the app key. Now the problem is that when I port this to the integration server, artisan uses different file names for those views, and seems to create new files with those new names.

How can I tell laravel to use the views that artisan created on my dev machine, even on the staging environment.

For troubleshooting I changed the app key on integration to be the same as my dev machine, but a) it didn't take care of the problem, and b) I'm sure that's not the intent.

Any help is *very* greatly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Files stored in `storage/framework/views` are cached views and basically there's no need to touch them directly.

Comment: alright, that's one step closer... now where are the originals?

Comment: In `resources/views` as usual, but do not expect the same files there. Final views (one that's cached) can be produced from many blade templates, so no 1:1